# Sql ranking query

Tags: rank

I have a requirement to make tier based on rank
Example first 5 ranks tier 1
Next 5 ranks tier 2
Next 3 ranks tier 3
Next 5 ranks tier 3

Kindly let me know if any help in the sql query for above requirement
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Please consider reading [ask] and taking a look at [help] when asking questions on the site. If possibly, please [edit] your question to include a better description of what you are trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the ranking functions.

[SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[MySql](https://hasura.io/learn/database/mysql/rank-functions/#:%7E:text=The%20ranking%20functions%20in%20MySQL%20are%20used%20to,is%20assigned%20to%20rows%20in%20a%20sequential%20manner.)

[Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-window.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think it matches the level of input...